# How to Convert Different Enities in a single XML string

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, model, xml-serialization

I have Converted a the Different entities in a List and now I have a master list containing the many list of different models.

```
   public static string xmlSerialize(List<Object> o)
            {
                XmlDocument xmlOut = new XmlDocument();

                foreach(var i in o)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //MemoryStream myMemStr = new MemoryStream();
                        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(i.GetType());
                        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, i);
                        xmlStream.Position = 0;
                        xmlOut.Load(xmlStream);

                    }
                }
                return xmlOut.InnerXml;
}
```

The above method converts the multiple List into a XML. But this code Overwrites the previous XML string in every loop run.
Is There any solution to get the single XML for every entity.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `XmlDocument` you keep overwriting?

Comment: need to do some functions over the xmlOut.InnerXml string.

Comment: Also need a all the data in a single Xml string.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890763/how-to-serialize-a-list-of-lists-with-the-type-of-custom-object

Comment: Return in foreach without condition? Your edit doesn't really make sense...

Comment: hantoun: I guess it make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO - the simplest solution here is to load xml into temporary XmlDocument and  then perform Import

Idea is the following

```
public static string xmlSerialize(List<Object> o)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlOut = new XmlDocument();

            foreach(var i in o)
            {
                var tmpDoc = new XmlDocument();
                using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //MemoryStream myMemStr = new MemoryStream();
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(i.GetType());
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, i);
                    xmlStream.Position = 0;
                    tmpDoc.Load(xmlStream);
                }
                var newNode = xmlOut.ImportNode(tmpDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild, true);
                xmlOut.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode); 
            }
           return xmlOut.InnerXml;
        }
```

Comment: In above code, for every iteration in foreach xmlOut doesn't contain any value. value is "" .

Comment: I will append code above - I have not run this code, but you need to load some root nodes to xmlOut first, and then appendChildren. Example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: your above code is helping me but the same question arises that how to load some root nodes to XmlOut first.

Comment: xmlOut.LoadXml("<root/>");

Comment: working fine. but let's say first loop contain 20 records so in xmlOut stores only 20th record only, not first 19 records.

Comment: You can try tmpDoc.DocumentElement instead of tmpDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild - depending on your xml - it may help